# Python linked list hacker rank

Tags: python, python-3.x

I solved the problem but before that I was trying something else which didn't work.

```
def insert(self,head,data):
    if (head == None):
        head = Node(data)
    else:
        current = head
        while current != None:
            current = current.next
        current = Node(data)
    return head
```

This is what I did first then I did this

```
def insert(self,head,data):
    if (head == None):
        head = Node(data)
    else:
        current = head
        while True:
            if(current.next == None):
                current.next = Node(data)
                break
            current = current.next
    return head
```

Here is the link to the problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-linked-list

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well obviously it's not going to work because here:

```
current = head
while current != None:
    current = current.next
current = Node(data)
```

you **iterate** until `current` is `None`, then you create a new node and set the **local variable `current`** to that node. The `next` of the previous however **is still `None`. You thus need to set the `next` of the previous. You can for instance do that with:

```
current = head
while current.next != None:
    current = current.next
current.next = Node(data)
```

A minor improvement is to use `is not None` instead of `!= None`: since there is only one `None` you can use reference equality (`is`).

Comment: Oops......forgot that there is nothing initially and that this will only help in traversing the list.